# Run a service as if in a "run as administrator" cmd.exe

Tags: administrator, windows-services

I have a service that needs to run as a user X, but with administrator privileges. X is a local administrator.

The `%USERPROFILE%` - from the perspective of the service - should be X's home. This is the behaviour one sees in cmd.exe when started with "run as administrator" while logged in as X.

If I set the user for the service to X, it can start but does not have administrator privileges. If I set it to .\Administrator then the service fails to start with a "log on error"

Comment: Why does it have to be a service and not just a scheduled task?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the task scheduler system, but I need this process to start at startup regardless of whether anyone has logged in and I also need it to automatically restart if it terminates, so services seemed to fit the bill.

Comment: Odd. Services should run at the highest UAC privilege level by default.

Comment: Which can be done using the task scheduler. As you need to run it as a specific user with a specific home and a user profile, it's unlikely that what you're running is actually a service.